# Prevent AJAX calls when users are not logged in

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs3

ExtJS version: 3.2.1 (I know it's old... I cannot change this yet)

I am trying to prevent ajax calls once a user's authentication is no longer valid (either timed out or logged out)

When I override Ext.Ajax.response globally, that gets overwritten when I create a new Ext.Ajax call.

```
Ext.override(Ext.Ajax.request, {
    success: function(response, opts) {
        console.log('Override function');
        /* redirects to login page */
    }
});

/* lots of other code */

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/my_ajax_url',
    params: {type: 'producer'},
    success: function(r) {
        console.log('my function that does lots of stuff');
    }
});
```

I am trying to prevent myself from going through hundreds of files (130MB of nothing but code) changing all Ext.Ajax and Ext.data.JsonStore instances to call some sort of 'parent' function before everything.

I have also tried changing the response from returning a JSON object to returning an http error "HTTP/1.1 419 Authentication Timeout". I think this should be the way to go but I cannot get the 419 error to be 'caught' (I don't know exactly what to override to achieve this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of events on Ext.Ajax, where you can attach global listeners.

To prevent requests from being fired you can use [beforerequest](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-event-beforerequest) and return false in your listener:

```
Ext.Ajax.on({
    'beforerequest': function() {
        if (!loggedIn) {
            return false; // prevents request
        }
    }
});
```

There's also [requestcomplete](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-event-requestcomplete) and [requestexception](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-event-requestexception), where you could check for the HTTP status code (don't know which of the two a HTTP 419 would fire):

```
Ext.Ajax.on({
    'requestcomplete': function(conn, response) {
        if (response.status == 419) {
            // redirection to login page
        }
    }
});
```

(documentation links are for 3.4.0, but all events should be available in 3.2.1 as well)

Edit: Documentation for [ExtJS v3.2.1](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/docs/)

Comment: Awesome, this works for my Ajax problem. I also found a solution for my JsonStore issue:
 
`Ext.util.Observable.observeClass(Ext.data.Connection);

    Ext.data.Connection.on('requestexception', function(dataconn, response, options){

        if (parseInt(response.status) === 419) {

            window.location = '/login';

        }

    });`

Answer (score 1):

`request` is a method, so you can't override it in that fashion. Instead, you want something like this (untested):

```
var original = Ext.Ajax.request;
Ext.Ajax.request = function() {
    if (everythingIsFine) {
        original.apply(Ext.Ajax, arguments);
    }
}
```